# jQuery multiple Sortable lists on one page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a page that can have several different media galleries on one page. Each gallery thumb is 'sortable' in edit mode. This works find for the first one, but each additional gallery won't sort. I believe this is due to the fact that each sortable list is set to the container with class `.dynamic_med_gallery` so each additional sortable is trying to use that first div container with class `.dynamic_med_gallery`. How can I set each container to `$(this)` to keep each one separate and unique?

```
function sort_thumbs() {
   if (edit_mode == 'on') {
      var cont = $( ".dynamic_med_gallery" );
      cont.sortable({
         tolerance: 'pointer', 
         containment: cont, 
         items:'.dynamic_thumb',
         stop : function() {
            cont.addClass('update_index')
         }
      }).disableSelection();
   }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick for you. http://jsfiddle.net/qBzRC/27/

```
edit_mode = 'on';
if (edit_mode == 'on') {
    $(".dynamic_med_gallery").each(function () {
        $(this).sortable({
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            containment: $(this),
            items: '.dynamic_thumb',
            stop: function () {
                $(this).addClass('update_index'); // Not sure what this is for... might need changing depending on your needs.
            }
        }).disableSelection();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Robert, I appreciate it. The "$(this).addClass('update_index');" is so I can check to see what galleries have been updated on save.

Comment: $(this).addClass('update_index'); this will be used to update index of rows on db level, so next time items load from db. this will be good to find using classname and each loop and show items based on item_index.

Answer (score 1):

I put some more thought into it and worked it out as follows:

```
function sort_thumbs() {
    if (edit_mode == 'on') {
        $( ".dynamic_med_gallery" ).each(function() {
            cont = $(this);
            var this_id = cont.attr('id');

            cont.sortable({
                tolerance: 'pointer', 
                containment: cont, 
                items:'.dynamic_thumb',
                stop : function() {
                      $('#'+this_id).addClass('update_index');
                }
            }).disableSelection();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Your revision should work, but can be more efficient. I have added another answer below.